# Excel VBA- Run time error 9 (Subscript out of range)

Tags: vba, excel

i getting run time error 9 when i trying to execute the program with the following code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim varResponse As Variant

    varResponse = MsgBox("Are you sure want to add this ?", vbYesNo, "Selection")
    If varResponse <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ctl As Control

If Me.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
 MsgBox "Please enter #.", vbOKOnly
 Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
 Exit Sub
 End If
If Me.txtdescription.Value = "" Then
 MsgBox "Please enter a description.", vbOKOnly
 Me.txtdescription.SetFocus
 Exit Sub
 End If
 ' Write data to worksheet
 RowCount = Worksheets("Secretarial Jobs Description").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
 With Worksheets("Secretarial Jobs Description").Range("A1")
 .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
 .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.txtdescription.Value


 End With
 ' Clear the form
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
ctl.Value = ""
ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
ctl.Value = False
End If
Next ctl

End Sub
```

Whereby the debug part highlighted that

```
 RowCount = Worksheets("Secretarial Jobs Description").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
     With Worksheets("Secretarial Jobs Description").Range("A1")
```

is where the error had found. Am i having mistake on the code?

Comment: Is `Secretarial Jobs Description` sheet existing in your current workbook? You are sure that there are no typos, supplemental/missing white chars or letter case differences between the VBA code and the sheet itself?

Comment: Are you running the macro from the same workbook as the data, or a separate one??

Comment: Here are the Mircrosoft Excel Object
Sheet1(Disbursement)
Sheet2(Client)
Sheet3(Worksheets)
Sheet4(User)

Comment: Where is the `Secretarial Jobs Description` sheet located??

Comment: it located on Sheet3(Worksheets)

Comment: unhide the sheet, or activate if before, or use `thisworkbook.sheets("Secretarial Jobs Description").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` ,  if you have multiple workbooks opened.

Answer (score 0):

"Subscript out of range" is the error generated when an item is not found into a collection by its name or its index. It's highly likely that there is no worksheet in your current workbook that is (exactly) named "Secretarial Jobs Description".

Answer (score 0):

Like has been said, it must be that the sheet name you're calling for is incorrect or doesn't exist.

You could try referencing the sheet by it's object number:

```
RowCount = Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
```

Then it won't matter what it's called, just what place it is in.